# I want to print alternate words in a string array

Tags: java, arrays

```
class Test3
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String str[] = new String[] {"bharani"};
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i += 2)
        {
            System.out.println(str[i]);
        }    
}
```

What is the error? I am getting error as invalid main.

Comment: I'm guessing this is… *mumble mumble clairvoying…* [tag:java]…?

Comment: Which programming language are you using? It could be literally anything, for all we know this could be Python and the reason it's not working is because it's written like Java/Actionscript. Please let use know which programming language you're using.

Comment: Not literally “literally anything”. Not Pascal. Not BASIC or COBOL. But there were countless possibilities until we got the language tag added to the question. @TrampolineTales

Answer (score 0):

hi @ Munikotibharani Gopal. Your for loop condition is wrong. You have hardcoded `i < 7`. It won't work because your string array length is 1.
So, test the following code to design a `for` loop that depends on the length of your array.

```
public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String str[] = new String[] {"bharani","name1","name2","name3","name4","name5"};
        for(int i = 0; i<str.length; i++)
        {
          System.out.println(str[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String str[] = new String[] {"bharani","name1","name2","name3","name4","name5"};
        for(int i = 0; i<str.length; i+=2)
        {
          System.out.println(str[i]);
        }
    }
}

try this hope it helps:)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).